# SUM the RatingColumn in SQLite

Tags: ios, sqlite

I have a SQLite Table with columns as mentioned below,

```
Table1
ID, Topics,    Rating, Comments
1   topic1      3      none
2   topic1      4      none
3   topic2      2      none
4   topic2      4      none
```

I want to add the rating column for all the topic1, topic2 using sqlite query.
How can this sqlite query be formed?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `SUM()` [aggregate function](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_aggfunc.html) for achieving this.

You can do it like:

```
SELECT SUM(Rating) from Table1 WHERE Topics="topic1";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *getQuery = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT SUM(Rating) from Table1 WHERE Topics='topic1'"];
```

Then pass this to below method

```
-(NSMutableArray*) getRecords :(NSString*)getQuery isCheckOperationId:(BOOL)checkOperation
{
const char *dbpath = [databasePath UTF8String];    
if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &database) == SQLITE_OK)
{
    const char *query_stmt = [getQuery UTF8String];

    sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, query_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL);
    NSMutableArray *jsonArray = [NSMutableArray new];
    while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW)
    {
        NSMutableArray *objectColumn = [NSMutableArray new];
        NSMutableArray *keysColumn = [NSMutableArray new];
        for (int i=0; i < sqlite3_column_count(statement); i++) 
        {
            [objectColumn addObject:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, i)]];
            [keysColumn addObject:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(const char *) sqlite3_column_name(statement, i)]];
        }

        NSArray *objects=[[NSArray alloc]initWithArray:objectColumn];
        NSArray *keys=[[NSArray alloc]initWithArray:keysColumn];
        NSDictionary *dict=[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:objects forKeys:keys];
        [jsonArray addObject:dict];
       }

    [self closeDatabase];
    return jsonArray;
}

return nil;

}
```

Hope this helps you !!!

Comment: Thanks Arpit, i wanted the sql query only.